# Passing type to method and then calling method which is known to exist on that type

Tags: c#

I hate to post what is so similar to what's been asked before but I've read 15 different answers and still haven't managed to solve my problem.

I have two files. The first declares a generic type and passes it to the second as an argument. The second needs to typecast an object using this passed value and call a method on it. There is no firm binding that the method will exist, and that's maybe where my problem lies. It's part of an 'unofficial' protocol, e.g. not enforced by the code.

Here's the first file:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

[CustomEditor(typeof(RampSectionEditMode))]
public class RampSectionEditModeMeta : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        new CustomEditorMeta().HandleGenericUpdate(typeof(RampSectionEditMode).MakeGenericType(), target);
    }
}
```

Here's the script which uses the passed type:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CustomEditorMeta : Editor {

    public void HandleGenericUpdate (   System.Type script_type, Object target) {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Update")) {
            if (target.GetType() == script_type) {
                var script = (script_type)target; // <=== PROBLEM IS HERE
                script.updateEditorState();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I'm noticing at the `(script_type)target` line is *variable is being used as a type*.

**important note**

I cannot use the *dynamic* keyword because of limitations of my platform (Unity, which doesn't have official support for this level of C# as far as I'm aware).

Thank you.

**edit**

the `target` is an instance of this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class RampSectionEditMode : MonoBehaviour {
    public void updateEditorState () {
      // content omitted
    }
}
```

This does work if I hard-code the target type `RampSectionEditMode` instead of using `script_type`, but the whole point of the `CustomEditorMeta` class is to abstract this.

Comment: I thought MakeGenericType needs a Type to use as GenericTypeParameter. What are you trying to do with this statement?

Comment: @Nikolaus That was honestly kind of a shot in the dark, if you have advice for how to fix it I'd really appreciate it. In short, I already have the instance of the object (`target`) and know the name of a method which will exist on it (`updateEditorState`). All I need is a way to actually _call_ this method.

Comment: not sure I understand your problem but it sounds as something you should handle with reflection

Comment: It seems to me that you could benefit greatly by just creating an interface that your "dynamically chosen types" inherit from.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma I'm pretty new to C#, and not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: I've edited my answer to integrate Frederico's suggestion.

Comment: @maxpleaner For MakeGenericType() just remove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Reflection:

```
if (target.GetType() == script_type) 
{
     script_type.GetMethod("updateEditorState").Invoke(target,null);
}
```

You could also follow federico-dipuma's advice and create an interface:

```
public interface IUpdatable
{
    void updateEditorState()
}
```

and implement it by your class:

```
public class RampSectionEditMode : MonoBehaviour, IUpdatable
{
   public void updateEditorState ()
  {
       // content omitted
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but I'm having some other issues now. Will probably accept this shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to call "some" method on "some" object (like WCF invokers, for example), I often use this extensions:

```
using System;

namespace TEST
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static object Invoke(this object obj, string method, Type[] types, object[] args)
        {
            return obj?.GetType().GetMethod(method, types)?.Invoke(obj, args);
        }

        public static object Invoke(this object obj, string method, params object[] args)
        {
            return obj.Invoke(method, new Type[0], args);
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(4.Invoke("ToString"));
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call whatever you want.